# how to call function that return react jsx programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to show some toast message in application, and i try to write some function for this job, but i don't know how can i return some jsx from function to my component  programmatically

```
export const toast = (message) => {
    return (
        <div>
         example
        </div>
    )
}
```

the component that call toast function

```
export const comp = () =>{
    const clickEvent = () => {
        toast('example text');
    }
    return(
        <button onClick={clickEvent}>
            toast
        </button>
    )
}
```

Comment: What about changing `toast` into `Toast` and use it like a regular component?

Comment: Because it's so much easier that I plan to use it in many places. That's why I'm trying to write it like a function

Comment: But a non-class react component is already a function?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I am looking for a way to solve this problem for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function *is* "returning JSX".  But the code doesn't *do anything* with that returned JSX.  Though overall I think you're taking the wrong approach entirely here.

First, make your "toast" into a React component.  It *very nearly* is one, all you need to do is correct the casing in the name and destructure the props:

```
export const Toast = ({message}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {message}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then *use state* to conditionally show/hide that component in your markup.  For example:

```
export const Comp = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const clickEvent = () => {
    setMessage('example text');
  };

  return(
    <>
      <button onClick={clickEvent}>
        toast
      </button>
      {
        message.length > 0 && <Toast message={message} />
      }
    </>
  );
};
```

You can even move that conditional logic into the component itself if you like:

```
export const Toast = ({message}) => {
  return message?.length > 0 ? (
    <div>
      {message}
    </div>
  ) : null;
};
```

Which simplifies usage:

```
export const Comp = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const clickEvent = () => {
    setMessage('example text');
  };

  return(
    <>
      <button onClick={clickEvent}>
        toast
      </button>
      <Toast message={message} />
    </>
  );
};
```

However you organize the logic is up to you, there are endless variations.  But overall the point is that you don't want to *return JSX from a click handler*, because:

1. An event handler doesn't do anything with a return value.
2. Manually appending markup to the page is generally the wrong approach in React.

Instead, define your markup for your component to include the various elements that are *conditionally* included, and manage those conditions through the updates of state values.

Comment: David, I really appreciate your time and help, it is very valuable to me. I plan to use this function in many components. We would like to write its logic in such a way that I don't have to define a state for it in that component every time I want to use it.

Comment: @hosseinranjbar: You don't *have to* use state in order to pass a string to that component.  That string can come from anywhere.  State is being used in this example to illustrate how to dynamically show/hide something in a component.  The display ( or lack of display) for that child component represents two different "states" of the parent component.  One "state" in which the toast is shown, and one in which it is not.  And *in general* when you want to track the different states of a component you would use, well, *state*.  Perhaps you could elaborate with an example of what you're doing?

Comment: @hosseinranjbar: Keep in mind that this doesn't need to be state tracked in each individual component.  If you just want one "toast" for the entire application then you can use a more global state management system, such as `useContext` or Redux, to track a single "message" value across the entire application.